# Python: Импорт через __init__.py в IDE работает, а в командной строке - нет

Tags: python, python-import

У меня есть бот, который основан на уже готовом проекте, и вот пришло время писать и своего. Решил сделать такой же импорт плагинов:

```
# содержимое /plugins/__init__.py
import importlib
import pkgutil

__all__ = []

def import_plugins(package):
    if isinstance(package, str):
    package = importlib.import_module(package)

    for loader, name, is_pkg in pkgutil.walk_packages(package.__path__):
        full_name = package.__name__ + '.' + name

        module = importlib.import_module(full_name)

        for name in dir(module):
            if name[0] == "_":
                continue

            e = module.__getattribute__(name)

            if e in __all__:
                continue

            if True:
                __all__.append(e.__name__)
                globals()[e.__name__] = e

        if is_pkg:
            import_plugins(full_name)


import_plugins(__name__)
```

Так вот, с запуском из PyCharm проблем нет, но если запустить из командной строки, то выдаст ошибку:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "Camelia.py", line 12, in 
>       settings = Settings.Settings()
>     File "C:\Users\ShadowOfLife\PycharmProjects\AeterrnoPy\Settings.py", line 10, in __init__
>       self.inner_data = InnerDataPlugin()
>   NameError: name 'InnerDataPlugin' is not defined

Что я делаю не так? Есть ли возможность заставить такой импорт работать с командной строки?

Структура проекта:

> /Plugins
>   -- /AeterrnoPy
>   -- /Base
>   -- /Data
>   -------- __init__.py
>   -------- InnerData.py  # тут находится InnerDataPlugin()
>   -- /EzPy
>   -- __init__.py # тут код для импорта
>   /utils
>   Camelia.py # бот
>   Settings.py # сюда импортируются плагины

И содержимое Settings:

```
from Plugins import *


class Settings:
__slots__ = ("inner_data", "plugins", "user_plugins")

def __init__(self):
    self.plugins = ()
    self.user_plugins = ()
    self.inner_data = InnerDataPlugin()

    self.plugins = (
        AntiFloodPlugin(),
        self.inner_data,
        PairPlugin("pair test", "pt"),
        TestingPlugin("test", "tst"),
    )

    self.user_plugins = (
        PairUP("pair test", "pt"),
    )
```

UPD: Извиняюсь за использование изображений, исправил

Comment: Замените изображения в вопросе текстом.

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: В каком файле определен `InnerDataPlugin`?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что Pycharm автоматически добавляет все директории с модулями проекта в PYTHONPATH.
Когда вы запускаете скрипт с консоли - он не видит директорий по которым раскиданы ваши модули (на это есть множество причин).
И выхода здесь есть два:

1. Правильный - просто используйте относительный импорт, например:

   from ..Plugins import *

   import .Plugins

(поексперементируйте с путями, чтобы самому понять как это всё работает)

2. Не очень правильный 
   Создайте в главной директории проекта **init**.py
   Импортируйте в него все свои внутренние модули
   Добавьте корневую директорию проекта в переменную PYTHONPATH вашей ОС, или же непосредственно в самом верху главного файла пропишите:

   import sys

   sys.path.append('/path/to_my_project')

Answer (score 0):

В общем, ответ Alex мне не помог, ничего не изменилось. Проблему уже решил, но почему и как - объяснить не смогу. Импортировал в __init__.py базовый плагин, от которого наследуются остальные, и вместо того, чтоб добавлять в __all__ всё подряд, добавляю только подклассы BasePlugin. Теперь работает и с консоли, и с PyCharm, и с другого устройства тоже.
То есть, вместо:

```
if True:
    __all__.append(e.__name__)
    globals()[e.__name__] = e
```

Теперь:

```
if isinstance(e, type) and issubclass(e, BasePlugin) and e.__module__ == module.__name__:
    __all__.append(e.__name__)
    globals()[e.__name__] = e
```

Нужные плагины в переменной были в обоих случаях, но почему-то при наличии там чего-то лишнего импорт не срабатывал в командной строке.